# css min-width and auto width combination

Tags: html, css, width

I want a div to be minimum of certain width but auto extend if the content is more. I have tabbed menu options in form of short codes and each option is of 2 characters. There are certain options that can span to 3, 4 or more characters. Whenever a option of more than 2 characters is to be shown, the div should expand automatically. I have done this once in JavaScript but don't want to use here because I have too many items and primarily looking for a CSS based solution.

I have tried `min-width` and `auto` width at the same time but they do not work.

Following is my code:

```
.inner{
    width:auto;
    min-widht:23px;
    margin:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    height:23px;
    border: 3px solid #A3A0FA;
    border-radius: 1px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px transparent inset, 0px 0px 8px transparent;
    padding-left:5px;//Added after posting the question, this works for me
    padding-right:5px;//Added after posting the question, this works for me
}

<div class="inner">AB</div>
<div class="inner">ABCD</div>
<div class="inner">ABC</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't `inline-block` work exactly like that?

Comment: inline-block will place the next div inline but will not control the width of a div!! I am showing content inside the divs and divs have borders so when the content increase, the div should expand.

Comment: Then I suggest that you demo this issue with full information and existing code so that we don't have to guess at what the issue really is.

Comment: How about floating? - http://jsfiddle.net/h0uw493e/

Comment: `display: table`? - http://jsfiddle.net/x5ppLg00/

Comment: @Paulie_D I applied padding to left and right of the div thereby making it display as if its width was fixed for 2 characters and now when the content increases, it expands automatically. Really appreciate your prompt support and replies. Many thanks